# How to access my json data from type Any in swift?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to perform my network calls.  The return from the response(call below) returns a type ANY.  How do i get access to my array of dictionaries?

Almofire documentation:

```
 Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
debugPrint(response)

if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)")
   }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
let json2 = json as! [[String:String]]
```

JSON:

```
 (
    (
            {
        docURL = "https://httpbin.org/get/rab1Mpub.pdf";
        name = "rab1Mpub.pdf";
    }
),
    (
            {
        docURL = "https://httpbin.org/get/1Mpublic.pdf";
        name = "1Mpublic.pdf";
    }
),
    (
            {
        docURL = "https://httpbin.org/get/plantLabBook";
        name = "plantLabBook_1.pdf";
    }
)
)
```

I just get the following error:

```
 Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10740c648) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10740b1a8).
2018-03-16 15:46:16.501012+0000 labbook[12637:401862] Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10740c648) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10740b1a8).
```

Comment: It's an array of arrays of dictionaries. Try `[[[String:Any]]]`

Comment: Looks like you have a `[[[String:String]]]`

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array, of an array, of a dictionary:

```
let json = json as! [[[String:String]]]

for outer in json {
    for inner in outer {
        for (key, value) in inner {
            print(key, "has", value)
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: `as!` should be done only if you're absolutely sure of the object type. i.e that the API will always send `[[[String:String]]]`.

PS: I personally use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to make my life easier when I need to work with nested structures.

Comment: Do not use a forced cast. When the API changes or for any other reason, the app obtains a different result, you want to gracefully handle the changed data, not crash. Never assume a specific result. Code defensively.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, ofcourse. Using `!` is when you are absolutely sure it'll always be so. I banged here to keep the answer concise for the current context. Thanks for noting this though.